# How to combine two or more tables into one master table in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose we have two tables with the same headings on different sheets:

Sheet 1:

```
Subject
Biology
History
```

Sheet 2:

```
Subject
Maths
Biology
```

However, I have Sheet 3, which I'd like to be a combination of those two tables. I.e.

Sheet 3:

```
Subject
Biology
History
Maths
Biology
```

Also, if I update e.g. Sheet 1 with a new row to contain `Physics`, I'd like the table in Sheet 3 to reflect this, so that it becomes:

Sheet 3:

```
Subject
Biology
History
Physics
Maths
Biology
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? I thought that a simple `=` in the cells of Sheet 3 to reference Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 could work but this doesn't take into account how Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 can grow in size.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: The latest version with Office 365 @BigBen

Comment: Posted a solution, though just had a thought: how flexible are you on the order of the entries returned? Should all Sheet1 entries precede the Sheet2 entries?

Comment: I'd typically try this in powerquery.

Comment: @JvdV Absolutely! By far the better tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the *Sheet1* and *Sheet2* tables are [**Tables**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) named *Table1* and *Table2*:

`=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",1,T(IFNA(IF({0,1},Table1[Subject],Table2[Subject]),"")))&"</b></a>","//b")`

This being a dynamic array formula it will not be possible to enter it within a **Table**. Note also that character limitations on `TEXTJOIN` mean that this set-up might not be suitable for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`=IF(ROW()<MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C1);0);0);Sheet1!RC1;INDEX(Sheet2!C1;ROW()-MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C1);0);0)+1;0))`

Where:

`MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C1);0);0)` is the position of first blank cell in Sheet1

`ROW()<MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C1);0);0)` is true when Sheet1 has a value in the current row

`Sheet1!RC1` is the value in Sheet1 at the current row

`INDEX(Sheet2!C1;ROW()-MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C1);0);0)+1;0)` is the value in Sheet2, shifted to ensure the values of Sheet2 are below the values of Sheet1